# how to get the value of the only key-value pair in object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript object like below, **`a` has only one key-value pair**, how could I get the value of a1 **without using iteration** and also without knowing the key name(i.e a1) ?

```
a: {
            a1:"hello"
        }
```

Comment: in my case, it's bit special because the object has only 1 key-value pair, so I am asking how to get the value **without using iteration**

Comment: that is the same situation as in the duplicate question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you said you know there's only one key–value pair in the object:

```
var a = { a1: 'hello' };
Object.keys(a)[0];
var key = Object.keys(a)[0];
a[key]; // yields "hello"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through i belive.

```
var t = { 
         a: {
              a1:"hello"
            }
        }

for (u in t) {
    console.log(u); //Outputs "a"
    for (v in t[u]) {
        console.log(v + " " +t[u][v]); //Ouputs "ai hello"
    } 
}
```